# For loop cannot detect the row and column

Tags: excel, vba

My script can detect rows and column in first round but in the second round cannot detect rows and column.

It shows

> "run-time error '1004' : "\" could not be found.

Is there some missing code or is the sequence I put wrong?

```
Sub Conso()

   ' Get common values, eg. path, date
    Call getValues

    Workbooks("Daily Reporting Template.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("Master").Activate

    'Open Staff Input Value
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim j As Long
    'j = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To 30
        StaffPath = Cells(i, 4).Value
        Ws = Cells(i, 3).Value
        THPath = Cells(3, 2).Value
        wrkFold = Cells(2, 2).Value
        Filename = Cells(4, 2).Value

        'Open Template
        'Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        '  wrkFold & "Master TH\Template\Daily Reporting Template.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
        Windows("Daily Reporting Template.xlsm").Activate

        Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
          StaffPath & "\" & Filename & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3
        Cells.Select
        Selection.Copy

        Windows("Daily Reporting Template.xlsm").Activate
        Sheets(Ws).Activate
        Cells.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
          THPath & "Daily Reporting Template" & ".xlsm" _
          , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
          ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Windows(Filename & ".xlsm").Close

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to be explicit on ranges and avoid Activate and Select. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)

Comment: I assume you are not on the correct workbook/worksheet, or there is nothing in the next row

Comment: Maybe I describe on my coding. The purpose is because i have 3 and above different path to go copy the data and paste at different worksheet. Therefore,i develop the script to loop through the rows and columns that I assign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code picks the value based on active sheet. This causes issues during Loop since it just refers to different file. Try the following code.

**UnTested**

```
Sub Conso()

Dim DailyRptTemplate As Workbook, MasterSht As Worksheet, TempWbk As Workbook

   ' Get common values, eg. path, date
    Call getValues

    Set DailyRptTemplate = Workbooks("Daily Reporting Template.xlsm")
    Set MasterSht = DailyRptTemplate.Worksheets("Master")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    'Open Staff Input Value
    Dim i As Integer
    'Dim j As Long
    'j = Cells(Rows.Count, 13).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 7 To 30
        StaffPath = MasterSht.MasterShtCells(i, 4).Value
        WS = MasterSht.Cells(i, 3).Value
        THPath = MasterSht.Cells(3, 2).Value
        wrkFold = MasterSht.Cells(2, 2).Value
        Filename = MasterSht.Cells(4, 2).Value

    'Open Template
    'Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        'wrkFold & "Master TH\Template\Daily Reporting Template.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3

    Set TempWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StaffPath & "\" & Filename & ".xlsm", UpdateLinks:=3)

        TempWbk.Cells.Copy
        DailyRptTemplate.Worksheets(WS).Range("A1").Paste

        DailyRptTemplate.SaveAs Filename:=THPath & "Daily Reporting Template" & ".xlsm" _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
            ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
        TempWbk.Close (False)
    Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

It is also worth to have look at the below section since these are not looped through the procedure.

```
THPath = MasterSht.Cells(3, 2).Value
wrkFold = MasterSht.Cells(2, 2).Value
Filename = MasterSht.Cells(4, 2).Value
```